# Bootstrap 4 Dropdown on hide doesn't wait for animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a codepen to help explain: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oLZOyp
Basically, I've added two animations using `animate.css` to Bootstrap 4 show.bs.dropdown and hide.bs.dropdown, it works on the first show.bs.dropdown but not on hide.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //animate css function
  $.fn.extend({
    animateCss: function (animationName) {
      var animationEnd = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';
      $(this).addClass('animated ' + animationName).one(animationEnd, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('animated ' + animationName);
      });
    }
  });


  $('.dropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function () {
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).animateCss('flipInX');
  })

  $('.dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function () {
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).animateCss('flipOutX');
  })
});
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: You can't use it like this, because after you click on hide Bootstrap adds `display: none` immidiately. You can make it work that way on hover (not click). If you want hover behavior I can help you. And you use Bootstrap 4 CSS and Bootstrap 3 JS file in your Codepen.

Comment: Oops, fixed that. And that's what I thought too, [this](http://bootbites.com/demos/dropdown-effects/) seems to do it on click, however it is Bootstrap 3. Couldn't get it to work with Bootstrap 4 however.

Comment: It works for BS4 too. http://codepen.io/makshh/pen/VjpOaV (first dropdown)

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 0):

No need to use slides or other workarounds Here is a simple Solution :

1. Add **animate.css** to your project(google it everyone knows it)
2. Add **animated** class to your dropdown-menu
3. Use the following piece of Js:(show() is very important)

   ```
   $('.dropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function(e){
       $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').removeClass('lightSpeedOut').addClass('lightSpeedIn').show();
   });

   $('.dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function(e){
       $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').removeClass('lightSpeedIn').addClass('lightSpeedOut');
   });
   ```

   **Tested with Bootstrap 4.3.1(Currently Latest)**